# What is the proper way to ask for Extended Permissions on Facebook with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Should I still be using permissions.request or is there a new way to do this? I've seen conflicting info.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [`FB.login()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) with the `scope` parameter:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log('Logged out.');
       });
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Ironically, Facebook just [posted a tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/) related to this yesterday. Also I have written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-ask-for-extended-permission-in-your-facebook-application/32/) about this a while back.